# Evaluate entire buffer in skewer-mode

Tags: javascript, skewer-mode

`skewer-mode` has been a very useful tool for me learning JavaScript. I constantly use `skewer-eval-last-expression` and `skewer-eval-defun` for debugging purposes, but I find that most of the time I want to evaluate the entire script file I am working on, rather than a single function or expression. **Is there a way for me to evaluate the entire buffer, rather than just a function or expression?**

My current hack to get around this, is to just surround all the code I am working on in curly braces. That way when I call `skewer-eval-defun`, all the code within the braces is evaluated. However, it would be nice if there was a solution that didn't involve extra code that needs to be removed later (the extra braces affect indentation as well).

Comment: I have never used skewer-mode, but does `skewer-load-buffer` bound to `C-c C-k` do what you want?

Comment: @icarus unfortunately that does not do what I want, but thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Can you clarify what you want, and how that's different from what `C-c C-k` does?